# Google Maps Direction service sometimes fails 

Tags: javascript, google-maps

I used the following code to display a google Maps Direction from a Source to Destination and it was working fine when i used Towns in source and destination like : Cairo , Tanta

But if I used a certain Addresses as Source and destinations it is not working like :
Source : "Pizza station, Tanta, Al Gharbiyah, Egypt"
Destination : "Tanta, Tanta Qism 2, Al Gharbiyah, Egypt"

but it is working in the google maps main website http://g.co/maps/dvp2y

```
var directionsService = new google.maps.DirectionsService();
 var directionsDisplay = new google.maps.DirectionsRenderer();

 var map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map'), {
   zoom:7,
   mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP
 });

 directionsDisplay.setMap(map);
 directionsDisplay.setPanel(document.getElementById('panel'));

 var request = {
   origin: 'Tanta', 
   destination: 'Cairo',
   travelMode: google.maps.DirectionsTravelMode.DRIVING
 };

 directionsService.route(request, function(response, status) {
   if (status == google.maps.DirectionsStatus.OK) {
     directionsDisplay.setDirections(response);
   }
 });
```

Is there any way to give it the source address and destination address and return the way between them ?

Comment: Maybe try the official street address instead of just "Pizza station"?

Comment: but it is working in the google maps main website http://g.co/maps/dvp2y

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I get a direction when I use your origin and destination, but not the same as in the google-map.  I would assume that the google-map will request the places instead of geocoding the addresses, so you may do the same:

1. first request the locations using the places-library
2. then request the direction using the results from the places-request

Answer (score 0):

The official site might not use the same code like yours.

Try to see the status returned.

```
 directionsService.route(request, function(response, status) {
   alert(status);
   if (status == google.maps.DirectionsStatus.OK) {
     directionsDisplay.setDirections(response);
   }
 });
```